# How to save received messages in separate files with messagelistener

Tags: java, exception, jms, listener

Disk.class implementation

```
package server;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.ObjectMessage;

import services.CustomerData;

public class Disk implements MessageListener{

private int index;
private FileWriter f;
private BufferedWriter b;

public Disk(int i){
    this.index=i;
    try {
        f = new FileWriter("disk"+i+".txt",true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    b = new BufferedWriter(f);
}

@Override
public void onMessage(Message m) {
    try {
        if(m instanceof ObjectMessage){
            CustomerData c = (CustomerData) ((ObjectMessage) m).getObject();
            b.write(c.getSurname()+" "+c.getName()+" "+c.getAge());
            b.newLine();
            b.flush();
            System.out.println("disk"+index+".txt saved");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

So, what happens is that every message received by every message listener is saved in the same file (the last indexed disk.txt file) but I want to save them in every single file, from 0 to N. N txt files are created but they are not modified except the last one.

EDIT: I added the FileWriter and BufferedWriter in the Disk contructor but it will create N files but modify the last one only.

Main class there Disk is created:

```
package server;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.Topic;
import javax.jms.TopicConnection;
import javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.TopicSession;
import javax.jms.TopicSubscriber;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class StorageServer {

public static final int N = 10;

public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException {
    Hashtable<String,String> prop = new Hashtable<String,String>();
    prop.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
    prop.put("java.naming.provider.url", "tcp://127.0.0.1:61616");
    prop.put("topic.req", "requests");
    System.setProperty("org.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES","*");
    try {
        Context jndiCon = new InitialContext(prop);
        TopicConnectionFactory tConnFact = (TopicConnectionFactory) jndiCon.lookup("TopicConnectionFactory");
        TopicConnection tConn = tConnFact.createTopicConnection();
        TopicSession tSess = tConn.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Topic topic = (Topic) jndiCon.lookup("req");
        TopicSubscriber subscriber = tSess.createSubscriber(topic);
        tConn.start();
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
            //FileWriter file = new FileWriter("disk"+i+".txt",true);
            subscriber.setMessageListener(new Disk(i));
            System.out.println("New disk"+i+" started");
        }
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Are you sharing a single `FileWriter` with multiple `Disk` instances?

Comment: Edit the question to include the code there.

Comment: You should create the `BufferedWriter` in the constructor too, instead of creating a new one every time in `onMessage()`.

Comment: I edited the first post

Comment: Include the code where you're creating the `Disk` instances too, and setting them as listeners. You're using a `Topic` and not a `Queue` right? If not, then only one listener will get the message from the same `Queue`.

Comment: I added the main class in the first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a single `TopicSubscriber` which has a single `MessageListener` (hence the `setMessageListener` and not `addMessageListener`). You need to create a separate `TopicSubscriber` for each listener with

```
for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
    TopicSubscriber subscriber = tSess.createSubscriber(topic);
    subscriber.setMessageListener(new Disk(i));
    System.out.println("New disk"+i+" started");
}
```

I'd also recommend avoiding using the `FileWriter` (and `FileReader`) class, because it uses the platform encoding. This can cause surprises when platform (or its encoding) changes. The equivalent, but longer and safer way is:

`BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("whatever.txt"), "UTF-8"));`

With UTF-8 being a safe encoding to use.